# Pandas Dataframe on YFinance

Tags: pandas, yfinance

I am using YFinance to get some stock historical prices. Trying to convert the data to Json as data for JS Charting. The Yfinance dataframe treat the date column as index. As a result, I don't know how to access/print out the simple 'date' column. (You can tell I am beginner for python).

I've tried to read the dataframe document about to_json() and stuff like reset_index(). But I am so beginner that I cannot understand what they are saying.

All I really want is to generate a Json text from Yfinance dataframe for the javascript app on my web page like the following:

```
<script>
data = [{"date":"2020-11-20",
         "open":"1234",
         "high":"1245",
         "low":"999",
         "close":"1120",
         "volume":"1234566"},
        {"date":"2020-11-19",......
         .......
        }]
</script>
```

I am using a silly for loop to generate the text right now but I am sure there are much more elegant solution out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yfinance data is indexed by date, so df.to_dict(orient='records')` will be converted to the desired format.

```
import yfinance as yf

tickers = yf.Tickers('aapl')
df = tickers.tickers.AAPL.history(period="1mo")
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.drop(['Dividends','Stock Splits'], inplace=True, axis=1)
df.to_dict(orient='records')

[{'Date': '2020-10-21',
  'Open': 116.46906393914934,
  'High': 118.50555147489459,
  'Low': 116.24944161427659,
  'Close': 116.6687240600586,
  'Volume': 89946000},
 {'Date': '2020-10-22',
  'Open': 117.24771296653945,
  'High': 117.83670077073543,
  'Low': 114.39263813163417,
  'Close': 115.55064392089844,
  'Volume': 101988000},
 {'Date': '2020-10-23',
  'Open': 116.18954660696212,
  'High': 116.34927470261839,
  'Low': 114.08317994708769,
  'Close': 114.84187316894531,
  'Volume': 82572600},
 {'Date': '2020-10-26',
  'Open': 113.81364269517282,
  'High': 116.34926896680302,
  'Low': 112.6855840199125,
  'Close': 114.85185241699219,
  'Volume': 111850700},
  ...]
```